# Mix-blend-mode difference not working and background image of parent is in front of children regardless of z-index

Tags: css, reactjs, image, components, mix-blend-mode

Edit: Apologies, forgot to add the sandbox to tinker: https://codesandbox.io/s/inspiring-wing-tekl08

I'm having an issue with my CSS. To clarify, the reason I want to do this is because I want my text to have a `mix-blend-mode: difference` on `h1` within a media query, and after researching on here and other forums I've concluded that it's only possible if the background image which the text blends with is inserted via CSS instead of an `<img/>` in my React Component. If this is possible in any other way and I'm going about this wrong, feel free to give me a better option.

For some reason, the background image that I've inserted (see code below) is placing itself in front of `h1`. I've tried setting a `z-index: 1` on the image and `position: relative` - `z-index:something>1` on the text but it doesn't seem to work. Same goes for the `<Nav/>` tag that can be seen in the component - it ends up hidden behind the image.

Component:

```js
const PageHeader = () => {
  return (
    <motion.div
      id="header"
      variants={imgFade}
      initial="hidden"
      animate="show"
      className="bg-image"
    >
      <div className="header-container">
        <div className="title-container">
          <motion.h1
            variants={textAnimate(0.7)}
            initial="hidden"
            animate="show"
          >
            FNAME
          </motion.h1>
        </div>
        <br />
        <div className="title-container">
          <motion.h1
            variants={textAnimate(0.8)}
            initial="hidden"
            animate="show"
          >
            SNAME
          </motion.h1>
        </div>
        <Nav />
      </div>
    </motion.div>
  );
};

export default PageHeader;
```

CSS:

```css
.bg-image {
  background: url("img/compressed/Website\ Cover_Open_NoBG.png") no-repeat
    bottom right;
  background-size: contain;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  float: right;
}

.header-container {
  margin-left: 100px;
  margin-top: 200px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}

.title-container {
  overflow: hidden;
}

h1 {
  font-family: "Lato";
  font-size: 5rem;
  font-weight: 300;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: left;
  mix-blend-mode: color;

  pointer-events: none;
}
```

Apologies if it's blaringly obvious - again if someone can find an alternative to do the code below then I would much rather follow through with that:

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 1200px) {
  .h1 {
    mix-blend-mode: difference;
  }
```

Thanks!

Comment: Could you provide a *runnable* [mcve]?

Comment: @tao Apologies, completely forgot and just added a sandbox link at the start of the post.

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE: This has been solved by just putting `position: relative; z-index: 2` on `.header-container`. Perfect example of stopping coding after 3am or else you get blinders on and can't see the obvious answer.

In case anyone can help regarding `mix-blend-mode: difference` do let me know.

UPDATE 2: Second issue solved! Had to put a background color of white on the `background` property and also put the `mix-blend: mode` on `.header-container` - Text had to be changed to white and kept on `difference` blend even on a white backdrop.

Answer (score 0):

Good solution Ani.

In my case, I had to add `mix-blend-mode: difference;` on the `.header-container`, and `color: white; mix-blend-mode: difference;` on `h1`.